# Editor for both CheckBox and Text in a single column in Tree Table using NatTable

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am trying to recreate this "TreeGridWithCheckBoxFieldsExample" from the natTableExamples, and I wanted the first column editable, not only the Checkbox but also the Text it contains.
But when I register for TextCellEditor I am not able to set the CheckBox value by clicking it, if I click on CheckBox it goes to edit mode for the text beside it because of the MouseEditAction() in the below code.

```
uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstSingleClickBinding(
                    new CellPainterMouseEventMatcher(
                            GridRegion.BODY,
                            MouseEventMatcher.LEFT_BUTTON,
                            checkBoxPainter),
                    new MouseEditAction());
```

But if I remove it I won't be able to select the CheckBox, and because of DefaultBooleanDisplayConverter in the below code, the text after editing is not getting edited because the dataValue it gets is of boolean type .

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                    CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER,
                    new DefaultBooleanDisplayConverter(),
                    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    TreeLayer.TREE_COLUMN_CELL);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is afaik not supported out of the box. Converters and editors are registered per column/cell. Mixing two editors and converters in one column/cell for two different properties of one row object is nothing to achieve easily. You will need to implement custom mechanisms to achieve that.

Comment: By Custom mechanism you mean custom editor or custom widget (which contains both check box and text).

Comment: Custom editor with custom bindings to react on a click on the checkbox differently than a click on the text of the cell.